# Show value if value is not met in linq statement C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have this linq that if filtering out statuses and only shows "Qualified", "Submitted", "Processing","Funded" as Last Status, how I can add if status is not those shows LastStatus as N/A

```
public string LastStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return Loans
                .SelectMany(s => s.LoanMilestones)
                .Where(w => new List<string> { "Qualified", "Submitted", "Processing","Funded" }.Contains(w.Milestone))
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.MilestoneDate)
                .FirstOrDefault()?.Milestone;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Before the `return` add an `if`. If the value is null then return `"N/A"` otherwise return the value.

Comment: @Sach - I don't have value null, I want to say if value is not one of this list ("Qualified", "Submitted", "Processing","Funded") then return N/A

Comment: Without you providing details of your `Loan` class or sample data it's difficult for me to provide an example, but the idea remains the same. In the `get`, before returning, perform a check on the value that you are currently returning. If the value is one of those, then return it as it is, otherwise return `N/A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First huge problem with your code is that you're creating and filling a whole new list for every item in the initial array. And the second huge problem is that you're doing linear searches in the temporary array. With both of these issues in mind, you seem to want something like this:

```
        static readonly HashSet<string> validMilestones = new() 
        { 
            "Qualified", "Submitted", "Processing", "Funded"
        };

        public string LastStatus => Loans
            .SelectMany(s => s.LoanMilestones)
            .Select(w => validMilestones.Contains(w.Milestone) ? w.Milestone : "N/A")
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.MilestoneDate)
            .FirstOrDefault()?.Milestone;
```

The third huge problem with your code, by the way, is that you're using strings. Enums are in the language (in fact, in every language) for a reason: exactly this.

Comment: There's also a fourth one, the fact that you're sorting an entire collection just to get one value, but that's less of an issue if you're using this on top of an `IQueryable<>` rather than an `IEnumerable<>`, which you don't mention. It's definitely a sign of laziness on an enumerable though.